# How to create a dictionary from a dataframe if the key is used multiple times?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a Dataframe with Dates, Tickers and Close
Some rows have the same dates

```
key= date value= ticker value close

import pandas as pd

data = {'Ticker': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],
    'close': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index= 
['27/01/2022','27/01/2022','25/01/2022','24/01/2022','23/01/2022'])
df

          Ticker    close
27/01/2022  laptop  1200
27/01/2022  printer 150
25/01/2022  tablet  300
24/01/2022  desk    450
23/01/2022  chair   200
```

I'm trying to get a dictionary that looks like this

```
Key
27/01/2022 laptop : 1200, printer : 150
25/01/2022 tablet : 300
24/01/2022 desk 450
23/01/2022 chair 200
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want the dictionary to look like. It will help people understand what you're trying to do if you write the desired output formatted as a dictionary, rather than a table.

Comment: Please post your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As baileythegreen alludes to in a comment, your sample output isn't a valid dictionary. If you want the output

```
{'23/01/2022': {'chair': 200},
 '24/01/2022': {'desk': 450},
 '25/01/2022': {'tablet': 300},
 '27/01/2022': {'laptop': 1200, 'printer': 150}}
```

you can do

```
{date: dict(zip(sub_df['Ticker'], sub_df['close']))
    for date, sub_df in df.groupby(df.index)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think your answer should work great